# What does `(=>F)` mean in the orgmode scheduling prompt?

Tags: org-mode

Sometimes, when I schedule a TODO item, the prompt shows me `(=>F)`:

[image]

and sometimes it doesn't:

[image]

What is this character sequence trying to tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never noticed it before but searching for it in the code uncovered this snippet:

```el
    ...
    (when org-read-date-analyze-futurep
      (setq txt (concat txt " (=>F)")))
    ...
```

So it just tells you  that you are currently specifying a date in the future.

Why it is not shown in the other case is a bit mysterious, probably an omission: the code path is slightly diffrerent and the relevant variable (`futurep` in `org-read-date-analyze`) might be set in one code path but not in the other. But it is a *long* function and I have not gone through it in detail to verify that. You might want to submit a bug report.

Comment: What a bizarre thing to want to tag. It seems to me that scheduling things in the future is what most use cases want, and if anything should be tagged it should be attempts to schedule things in the *past*.

Comment: I agree, but I don't care enough to do anything about it :-)